# How do I make a clock second hand move with 4 jumps/ticks per second?

Tags: swift4, clock, milliseconds, seconds

**EDIT**: Needed help to get exactly 3 ticks per second, but that's not possible because of fractions. Double checking the real life clock I realized it actually moves 4 ticks per second, I'm thinking a quarter second is even and should be able to be exact. Updated the question since I can't get that to work either:

I'm building a clock that has three options of how the second hand will move. I've successfully made the seconds move 6° per second (1 "tick" per second) and one option with a seamless sweep (0.006° per millisecond). But I can't get my formula to work for my third option: having the second hand move exactly 4 times per second, i.e. 1.5° every quarter of a second).

This is the line of code for the second hand (I use CGAffiateTransform later, hence the radians):

`let quarterSecond = round(millisecond * 4.0 / 1000.0)`

`let tickingSeconds = (((1.5 * π / 180) * quarterSecond) + ((6.0 * π / 180) * second))`

This does what I want but I don't like the `round` as it makes the movement inexact. The whole timer interval is set to 0.001 and I have a hard time believing that you can't make the second hand move precisely 4 "ticks" per second without doing some uneven jerks every now and then.

Any ideas?

Comment: `round` will make the hand move at +0.125, +0.325, +0.625, +0.875. You may want to use `round(.down)` to get +0.00, +0.25, +0.50, +0.75.
Else it won't be in perfect sync with you movement on the `second`.

Comment: Note that `round(.down)` is the behavior of integer division (for positive numbers) so you might was well use integers to compute `quarterSecond`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you intuitively think as *ticking* is how often your expression changes value.

Here, your entire expression is constant except for `second`. Which means that your expression can only change when `second` change. If it is an integer, it can only change every second.

You need a variable that changes thrice a second, you can approximate that using `millisecond` and a truncation (to remove the fractional part):

`let thrice_a_second = (millisecond * 3.0 / 1000.0).round()`

Only then you can use that expression to compute the new position, knowing that it increases by 1 thrice a second.

Comment: Thanks! I got it to work with that constant. However, I think I can see a very tiny, uneven jerk once in a while as the second hand moves. Can the `round(...)` bit be responsible for that? I'm a little bit worried that the constant isn't exact. I need a very precise movement every thrice second, does the `round(...)` prevent it?

Comment: "I'm a little bit worried that the constant isn't exact" - a third of a second is 333.333... milliseconds and so your rounding splits a second up into 333ms, 334ms & 333ms parts. You are up against the fact that a decimal fraction cannot precisely represent 1/3 (and your decimal fractions are actually binary fractions), so you can never be *precise*. You could start with nanoseconds... However your "once in a while" is probably more down to the vagaries of timing in a non-real time OS than any differences in your fractions.

Comment: I've edited my question since I realized I'm actually after 4 steps rather than 3 per second. 0.25 being even I still haven't accepted that this is impossible to achieve. How can I make the expression to change its value every 0.25 second?